# Better way to wrap a link around an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Let's say I wanted to wrap a link around an element `<div id='foo'><button>Hello World</button></div>` using Javscript only.

I could do something like:

```
document.getElementById("foo").innterHTML = 
"<a href='#'><button>Hello World</button></a>"
```

But is there a better way to do it without retyping the entire innerHTML content? Perhaps by somehow more directory wrapping the button with a link?

*(the purpose of this is because I have a button that creates an effect when clicked that isn't compatible with old versions of IE, I'd like to insert a manual link for IE 6/7/8 if that useragent is detected)*

Comment: How does link help it - hover effect?

Comment: Well, the effect I was referring to was a sort of lightbox/window overlay containing content. In older IE versions clicking the button would simply lead to a static page with that same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this should work:

```
document.getElementById("foo").innterHTML = "<a href='#'>" + document.getElementById("foo").innterHTML + "</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner. I'll mark this as the answer if no one posts a better way in the near future.